# SAS Studio Log function

Tags: sas

I'm trying to use the log function in SAS Studio.

First I Imported my data:

```
proc import datafile="/folders/myfolders/FinalExam/data_question2.xlsx"

 out=Q2

 dbms=xlsx

 replace;

 getnames=yes;

run;
```

Which has 3 Columns. DMD CK and H. I'm trying to make a new variable that is the log of CK. I've been using this code:

```
LCK = Log(CK)
```

But everytime I do it, it says It's either says statement out of place or It also says expecting another symbol. Not sure how to get this log function working correctly. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a data step.

```
data Q2;
set Q2;
lck = log(ck);
run;
```

This goes through the Q2 data set, record by record, and calculates the `lck` variable.

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why I couldn't find this online. I guess I was just asking the wrong question. I finally found in the SAS studio program where it was able to do this for me and gave a code similar to that one. I realized what I was inputting wrong now. Thanks a million!